# CSS/HTML Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I've got a purely HTML/CSS image gallery, however due to the fact it uses `<a>` tags to change out the images, it also bumps the page down to the image. I've got a fixed navigation bar in place, and needless to say, it simply covers the images when the page is bumped down.

**The lovely CSS I'm currently using for the gallery**

```
#images {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
#images img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all linear 500ms;
    -o-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all linear 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 500ms;
}
#images img:target {
    opacity: 1;
}

#slider a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:5px;
    border: 1px solid #4D3132;
    padding: 0px 6px;
    color: #FFF;
}
#slider a:hover {
    background: #282F40;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

**And the HTML** (not the entire page of course, just the element.)

```
<div id="images">
<img id="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg" />
<img id="image2" src="http://i.imgur.com/qASVX.jpg" />
<img id="image3" src="http://i.imgur.com/fLuHO.jpg" />
<img id="image4" src="http://i.imgur.com/5Sd3Q.jpg" />
</div>  
<div class="center">
<div id="slider">
<a href="#image1">1</a>
<a href="#image2">2</a>
<a href="#image3">3</a>
<a href="#image4">4</a>

</div></div>
```

So, Is it possible to create a HTML/CSS gallery that doesn't bump the page around, or dosnt use `<a>` tags...?

I should also point out, I'm not looking to make a "slideshow" the images don't have to automatically change out.

Edit:

The Images themselves aren't moving, It's being bumped up because of the use of `<a>` tags.

Comment: Oh @Ruddy you're always so eager to help! ;)

Comment: @BeatAlex Always! I answered the question didn't I? :P

Comment: Haha, true to a point.. ;) @Ruddy

Comment: basicly use fixed position too for your images, a bit as lightboxlike does :)

Comment: This example works fine for me, no 'jumping' about.

Comment: [not]Working thing of what OP means(scroll out of view and then click image box) http://jsbin.com/yimekacu/1/edit

Comment: @Ruddy Yea, 'technically' you did... and 'technically' it’s not assault if it's an "accident"

It works because I've isolated the element lol, Pasteing the rest of my jumbled code would be a nightmare

Comment: @Hollis That's really good to know. I shall have an "accident" near you soon. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use JavaScript you could load your images in an iframe by setting a target attribute for your links.

```
<div id="slider">
    <a target="pictureFrame" href="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg">1</a>
    <a target="pictureFrame" href="http://i.imgur.com/qASVX.jpg">2</a>
    <a target="pictureFrame" href="http://i.imgur.com/fLuHO.jpg">3</a>
    <a target="pictureFrame" href="http://i.imgur.com/5Sd3Q.jpg">4</a>
</div>
<iframe id="images" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg" name="pictureFrame">
</iframe>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nillervision/rvtrq/

Comment: Normally I would consider Iframes to be the root of all evil; however, after spending several hours attempting to get something else to work, This seems to be the best option when using only HTML and CSS.

Comment: The biggest problem with iframes is that the loaded content is not part of your main pages DOM so you cant really apply CSS or JS to the loaded content. From a SEO point of view there are also no indication that the loaded content is associated with your main page besides from your links. So don't use this to load important text based content. But with just images as loaded content and hrefs pointing to them you should be ok with search engines.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a little bit of javascript magic. You can do this with both vanilla js and jQuery. I'm going to demonstrate an easy jQuery solution to your problem.

Since you use anchors for targeting the images, browser will automaticly scroll to the image that you selected. If the browser window is small and the image is displaced, there will be an ugly jumping effect.

Jquery code:

```
$('#slider a').click(function(event){

    // prevent default behavior of anchors
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the id of selected image
    var $id = $(this).attr('href');

    // hide previous image (if there is one)
    $('#images .target').removeClass('target');

    // show the selected image
    $('#images ' + $id).addClass('target');
});
```

CSS changes:

```
#images img:target
```

becomes

```
#images img.target
```

I hope this helps, and don't forget to include the jQuery library into your code.

Good luck!